# My displayed Tiled map is rendered with different tile indexes than in the editor in Slick2D. Why?

Tags: rendering, maps, slick, tiled

[image]

[image]

The first picture is what I have in the editor and the second one is what I got when I rendered my map.

```
@Override
public void init(GameContainer container) throws SlickException {
    this.container = container;
    this.map = new TiledMap("/src/main/resources/map/test2.tmx");
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    this.map.render(0, 0);
}
```

I would expect the two to be the same, but they're not. Why is that?

Edit : I solved the problem by removing the margin when I imported my tilset

Comment: When you solved the problem yourself, please post an own answer. That way you prevent the Community bot from annoying us by bumping the question up again and again because it doesn't consider it answered yet.

Comment: I suggest moving away from Slick2D. Try LibGdx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about in Slick2D, but in Unity this sort of problem can be caused by the engine not assigning indices to wholly transparent blocks. For example, if tiles 2-4 are totally transparent, Tiled would assign the fifth block as index 5 but Unity would assign the 5th block as index 2.

Work-arounds may include slicing a dummy image with a solid color and then overwriting it with your final image to keep the slicing information metadata, or just not having wholly transparent blocks in your tilesheet.